# Exposing base class enum without tediously listing enumerators

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, enums

In C++11, I can expose an enumerator which is `protected` in a base class, to users of a derived class, as follows:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    enum Waldo { hidden, found };
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Waldo;
}

void foo()
{
    Derived::Waldo w = Derived::Waldo::found;
}
```

Unfortunately, in C++03, `Derived::Waldo::found` is illegal, and `Derived::found` is met with `'Base::Waldo Base::found' is protected within this context`.

I could work around that by also writing a `using` for each enumerator:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Waldo;
    using Base::hidden;
    using Base::found;
}

void foo()
{
    Derived::Waldo w = Derived::found;  // works in C++03
}
```

but this can be really tedious to do if the enumerator has many enumerators. Is there a way to pull off this enum-exposing in C++03 without this tedium?

Comment: You have something 'protected' that you want degrade to 'public', at least you have a serious problem of design, IMHO ...

Comment: @jeanDavy: `protected` makes it accessible to derived classes. Since the derived class already has access, it seems reasonable for the derived class to do what it wants with it, including give access to clients of the derived class. It works like this for other types of class members (such as methods), it's only enumerations that have the annoyance I describe.

Comment: That's THE point ("it seems reasonable for the derived class to do what it wants with it") ! it is not reasonable. Read again Scott Meyers "Effective C++" ... ;-)

Comment: Out of curiosity: Can't you use an c++11 compiler or do you want to stay backwards compatible?

Comment: @MikeMB: I work on a codebase that on some platforms needs to be compiled with GCC 4.4, which doesn't have supported for `enum class`.

Answer (score 1):

SCNR!

```
struct Wrap
{
    enum Waldo { hidden, found };
};

class Base : protected Wrap
{
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Wrap;
};

void foo()
{
    Derived::Wrap::Waldo w = Derived::Wrap::found;
}
```

Edit: Or you put it inside:

```
class Base
{
protected:

    struct Wrap
    {
        enum Waldo { hidden, found };
    };
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Wrap;
};

void foo()
{
    Derived::Wrap::Waldo w = Derived::Wrap::found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there are lots of different ways to do this, depending on what you want to do with the enum. Here is one:

```
struct WaldoStates
{
    enum States{hidden, found};
};

class Base
{
public:
    typedef WaldoStates Waldo;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

void foo()
{
    WaldoStates::States state = Derived::Waldo::found;
}
```

Now, this is good if simply want the states to be accessible with something like *myClass::Waldo::hidden* in any class of the inheritance tree. If you want to be able to set different states for some of the derived classes, you may want to do something like this instead:

```
struct WaldoStates
{
    typedef int State;
};

struct DefaultWaldoStates : public WaldoStates
{
    enum States{hidden, found};
};

 struct OtherWaldoStates : public WaldoStates
{
    enum States{stillHidden, alreadyFound};
};

class Base
{
public:
    typedef DefaultWaldoStates Waldo;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

class OtherDerived : public Base
{
public:
    typedef OtherWaldoStates Waldo;
};

void foo()
{
    WaldoStates::State state0 = Derived::Waldo::found;
    WaldoStates::State state1 = OtherDerived::Waldo::alreadyFound;
}
```